# Предлоги и падежи

Tags: падежи

Между двух деревьев или же между двумя деревьями?

Comment: Предпочёл бы родительный падеж.

Comment: Выражение "между двух деревьев" короче, чем выражение "между двумя деревьями". Поэтому, при прочих равных условиях, я выберу выражение "между двух деревьев".

Comment: А можно сказать: между двух деревьев натянута веревка? Мне больше нравится: между двумя деревьями.

Comment: 1. Можно.

2. Я не возражаю, чтобы Вы сказали: "Между двумя деревьями натянута верёвка".

Comment: Вы не считаете, что  Т.п. изображает нашу пространственную ситуацию с большей точностью?  Дело в том, что в случае Р.п. союз МЕЖДУ  близок к союзу СРЕДИ, и тогда протянуть веревку  среди деревьев будет сложно.

Comment: Можно  и  среди  деревьев  верёвку  протянуть.  Зависит  от  контекста.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что это будут совсем разные веревки.

Comment: 1. София, я считаю, что:

1.1) "между V и W" = "between V and W",

1.2) "среди X, Y и Z" = "among X, Y and Z".

2. В русском языке есть падежи, а в английском языке падежей [почти] нет.

3. Я не исключаю, что можно создать такой диалект русского языка, в котором значение предлога "между" будет зависеть от используемого падежа.

Comment: Ну что за язык: between да among - вот и все возможности. А у нас и падежи, и предлоги, и различные сочетания из предлогов и падежей - какая палитра для художника слова!

Answer (score 4):

ЛИТЕРАТУРНОЕ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЕ ТЕКСТА (Розенталь и др.)

> Предлог между употребляется с двумя падежами: родительным и творительным: ср.: зажал винтовку между колен – ...между коленями. Например: Шумный и возбужденный говор поднялся между донских казаков (С. Злобин). – Половину листовок Матвей послал Мартыну с запиской, остальные поделил между фронтовиками (Г. Марков). Современному употреблению больше отвечает второй вариант (с творительным падежом). В немногих случаях употребление обоих падежей служит целям дифференциации значений, например: между двумя огнями (в прямом смысле) – между двух огней (в переносном смысле, фразеологическое сочетание). Ср. также во фразеологических сочетаниях: между четырех стен, пропускать между ушей, путаться между ног, сидеть между двух стульев, читать между строк и некоторых др.

[Ссылка](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Находиться между/меж двух деревьев, пройди между двумя деревьями.

Это если говорить о стилистике, 
Первый случай близок к фразеологизму, поэтому я предпочел бы именно такой вариант.
формально оба варианта возможны. 
Что касается второго случая, то тут скорее творительный поскольку речь идет о движении - там и раньше использовался преимущественно он. .

Answer (score 2):

В современном языке предлоги *меж, между* обычно употребляются с формой множественного  числа преимущественно творительного падежа: *между кустами, между деревьями, между рядами кресел.*

Стилистика говорит, что форма родительного падежа множественного числа в современном русском языке характерна для разговорной речи: *между (меж) бровей, между (меж) рук.* Возможно и различение значений: *Нос находится (где?) между глазами.* Но: *Врезать (куда?) промеж (между, меж) глаз.*

Родительный падеж  используется во фразеологизмах: между (меж) четырех стен, пропускать (пропустить) между ушей, путаться меж (между) ног.

Устарелым считается употребление формы родительного падежа множественного числа при пространственном значении, она используется в поэзии как книжное выражение:

И быстрый парус челнока

Между небес и вод летел.

*(В. А. Жуковский, "Шильонский узник")*

Однако при обозначении взаимодействия, взаимосвязи, взаимоотношений кого-, чего-либо с кем- или чем-либо эта форма может быть использована как нейтральная:

А дружбы между псов, как будто меж людей,

Почти совсем не видно стало.

*(И. А. Крылов, "Собачья дружба")*

При наличии числительных формы родительного и творительного падежей равноправны: *между двух точек - между двумя точками.*

В некоторых случаях падежные формы служат смысловой дифференциации: *между двумя огнями* (в прямом смысле) - *меж (между) двух огней* (переносное значение).

Предлоги *меж, между* могут употребляться и с формой творительного падежа единственного числа, но обязательно при двух управляемых словах (именах существительных или местоимениях): *между домом и садом, между сосной и липой, между огородом и сараями, между яблонями и вишней; между Онегиным и мной, между ним и Лизой, между ним и нами.*

Но не могут быть употреблены предлоги между, меж с формой родительного падежа единственного числа. Такое употребление является устарелым, хотя оно наблюдалось еще в XIX в.:

И слух между народа шел,
Что Щука Лисоньке
Снабжала рыбный стол.

(И. А. Крылов, "Щука")

[источник](http://www.rlspace.com/mezh-ruk-ili-mezhdu-rukami-predlogi-mezh-i-mezhdu/)

Comment: Даже в ХХ веке наблюдалось :  
> А. И. Куприн. Однорукий комендант (1923)  
Вся Россия от горя поникла. Злые шутки тогда **между народа** ходили. «Стряпали, мол, именинный пирог из солдатского мяса, да не выпекся».

Вообще ссылка замечательная, особенно *при наличии числительных формы ... равноправны*. Именно это я показал примерами из Нацкорпуса в комментах к ответу @Элен, но она его удалила, а мне лениво снова их искать и копировать тут)))

Comment: >Вся Россия от горя поникла. Злые шутки тогда между народа ходили. 
  
В другом значении.

Answer (score 1):

У Ожегова Р.п. имеет пометку "устаревшее" - соответственно, основным является Т.п., а Р.п. используется в устойчивых оборотах. Это можно объяснить различными значениями двух падежей.

Творительный падеж имеет обобщенное орудийное (инструментальное) значение, причем оно должно пониматься отвлеченно (грамматически): предмет в форме Т.п. способствует осуществлению действия, придает ему известный вид и образ. В частности, в сочетании с предлогом МЕЖДУ, Т.п. определяет ОБЛАСТЬ ДЕЙСТВИЯ как промежуток между двумя предметами.

Основным значением Р.п. с предлогом является отложительно-достигательное значение (сравнить: отойти от дерева, дойти до дерева, но: стоять между деревьями), значение области действия является для него вторичным (например, находиться среди друзей).

Таким образом, обозначение среды (пространственное, временное и др.)   с помощью предлога  МЕЖДУ  успешно передает Т.п., а значение Р.п. является вторичным, неточным и поэтому устаревающим.

Comment: Если у Ожегова устаревшее, сейчас бы умерло.

Comment: @behemothus, ваше высказывание ложно: у Ожегова - "устаревшее" __И__ сейчас - не умерло.

Comment: София: >предмет в форме Т.п. способствует осуществлению действия, придает ему известный вид и образ.

И потому может справиться в этой функции и без предлога *между*: винтовка зажата коленями, дом скрыт деревьями. Наличие здесь предлога *между* будет функциональной избыточностью. Но по факту он внедрился и поспособствовал потеснению род. падежа. И стоять, находиться можно как *среди друзей*, так и *между деревьев*,— без всяких но.

Comment: @stopkran    
Следоватеольно выск5азывание Ожегова -ложно.

Comment: Предложный и беспредложный Т.п. различаются по значению, что видно из вопросов: скрыт (чем?) деревьями - прямое орудийное значение, скрыт (где?) между деревьями - сущ. в Т.п. определяет область действия.

Comment: >Единственный мяч во встрече гости забили дальним ударом, причем голкипер «Монпелье» Журден комично **пропустил мяч между ног**, попытавшись отбить его.

Является ли в данном контексте употребление Р.п. - *вторичным, неточным и устаревающим*, или здесь просто устойчивый оборот?

Comment: @behemothus, это не наверняка. Ведь слово могло быть устаревшим и 40 лет назад, и сейчас (и не умереть). А могло быть устаревшим тогда и стать нормативным сейчас. Всё могло быть, всё может статься...

Comment: Вторичность, неточность и устаревание ОТМЕНЯЮТСЯ. Будем считать, что Его Величество Смысл управляет формой,и она устареет только в том случае, если  на что больше не годна и полностью совпадет в своем значении с другой формой. Но Язык рационален и практичен, и он может заставить "устаревшую" форму работать на новый смысл, передавать оттенки смысла.

Comment: А теперь рассмотрим эту версию на примерах. 1) Предлог МЕЖДУ (МЕЖ)  (управление Р.п.) может совпадать по значению с предлогом СРЕДИ: Змея мелькнула меж (среди)камней. Форма "между камнями" имеет  в данном случае нежелательную точность.  2) Пропустить мяч лучше  "между ног":  - если сказать "между ногами", то непонятно, кому эти ноги принадлежат (точный Т.п. подразумевает, что это разные предметы). 3) зажать мяч "между ног" - здесь просматривается орудийный беспредложный Т.п. - фактически это "зажать мяч ногами", но способ действия подкорректирован.

Answer (score 1):

В современном языке - творительный падеж

Comment: Все зависит от автора и стилистики :  
>**Иван Ефремов**  
Туманность Андромеды (1956)  
Мвен Мас снова взял за руку Онар и повел ее **между кустов**, чувствуя ненавидящий взгляд Бета Лона.  
Час быка (1968-1969)  
Ожерелье этого же металла в виде узорных квадратов, соединенных розовыми камнями с алмазным блеском, охватывало высокую шею и спускалось четырьмя сверкающими подвесками в ложбинку **между грудей**, едва прикрытых фестонами упругого корсажа.  

Давайте попробуем заменить на Т.п.?