# В чем отличие "между деревьев" и "между деревьями"

Tags: выбор-слов, фразеология, морфемика, значение

По сути ничего кроме окончания не отличается. Но изменение окончания должно как-то влиять на значение.

Comment: http://rusgram.narod.ru/2697-2712.html (см.  § 2705)

Comment: Спасибо За помощь.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Смысл не меняется. В словарях указывается, что использование родительного падежа с этим предлогом — разговорный стиль (в нескольких значениях — устаревшее).

[http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?all=x&word=между](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?all=x&word=%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83)

Answer (score 4):

В обычных текстах употребляются обе формы, причем по семантике их различить трудно. Но частотность больше у формы ***между деревьями*** (500:90).

Исключение составляют фразеологизмы.

*Тропа петляла **между деревьев**. **Между деревьями** ― мраморные статуи, посеревшие от времени.*

Повтор вопроса:

[Предлоги и падежи](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/28578/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8)